# Is there a way in Python to tell specific function how to manipulate with my class objects?

Tags: python

Can I tell some function from another package how to manipulate with my user-defined class objects?

For example, I have a class:

```py
class Complex:
    def __init__(self, real, imag):
        self.real = real
        self.imag = imag
    // ...

z = Complex(3, 5)
```

I want somehow to override math.sin() function to work with my complex numbers, like:

```py
z1 = math.sin(z)
```

This should create new complex number according to the formula:
sin(a + bi) = sin(a)*cosh(b) + icos(a)*sinh(b)

Call

```py
print(z1)
```

should print

```py
/// 10.472508533940392 - 73.46062169567367i
```

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Since you have to write the entire implementation anyway, you should just put it in your own module. Note that your implementation likely depends on the default implementation of `math.sin()`.

Comment: Override the relevant dunder ```__ __``` methods?

Comment: @JoshuaNixon Is there a `__sin__` method? Or do you mean `__mul__` and `__add__` which are useful to implement the formula given but don't give any help for overriding `math.sin()` itself.

Comment: Couldnt you override mul, sub, add etc? He just wants ```math.sin``` to work with his class. Can simply override his own class

Comment: FWIW, Python already has a complex type and [cmath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmath.html) to work with them. I don't mean to discourage you. Implementing these yourself is a reasonable learning exercise.

Comment: @JoshuaNixon It's not clear that overriding the basic arithmetic operations would be sufficient. The algorithm to take `sin()` of a real number is entirely different than the one to take the `sin()` of a complex number.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I've heard of cmath and already tested numpy.sin() and it works fine with python complex numbers, but I was wondering if there is a way to override some functions, more precisely, to 'upgrade' them to work with more stuff, like my own complex numbers, list of my complex numbers, set of complex numbers, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to write your own method for your class.
Otherwise, you can use something called 'monkey patching'.

```
import math
def sin(x):
    do_stuff...

math.sin = sin
```

But in my opinion still, it would be a better idea to write a new function for your class

Comment: Note that this only replaces `math.sin` within the current module. It doesn't replace it when it is imported into other modules.